# How to animate width of native-react component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

I am using Animated API `import { Animated } from 'react-native'`

When specifying `width: animated-value` in the style, the `width` is actually only rendered once, and doesn't change dynamically. You can only see that the animated value behind the scenes is changing if you cause the element to re-render.

```
// since only function components can use hooks, wrap the classical component in a function one
// that sets up the hook for it
function withAnimationHook(Component) {
  return function WrappedComponent(props) {
    const anim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
    useEffect(() => {
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.sequence([
          Animated.timing(anim.current, {
            toValue: 1, 
            duration: 2000,
          }),
          Animated.timing(anim.current, {
            toValue: 0, 
            duration: 2000,
          }),
        ])
      ).start();
    }, []);
    return <Component {...props} anim={anim} />;
  }
}

class AnimatedButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { anim, width } = this.props
    return (
      <Animated.View style={{  width: width * anim.current._value }}>
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}

export default withAnimationHook(AnimatedButton)
```

I know setting up the animated value works because `style={{ transform: [{ scale: anim.current }] }}` works perfectly (it grows and shrinks repeatedly).

Why doesn't `width: width * anim.current._value` animate the width?

How can I animate the width?

`this.props.width` is just a number btw, e.g. `64`

Answer (score 1):

let try this.

```
const SubView = ({ parentValue = 0, propWidth=2000 }) => {
  const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: parentvalue,
      duration: 2000,
    }).start()
  }, [parentValue])

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        styles.viewStyle,
        {
          width: animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, propWidth],
          }),
        },
      ]}
    ></Animated.View>
  )
}

export default React.memo(SubView)
```

Comment: The only important change was using `.interpolate` right? The rest of the code in your answer seems to not be important to the answer

Comment: Instead of `width * anim.current._value` it should have been `anim.current.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [0, width] })`

Comment: yes,
and in your code
<Animated.View style={{  width: width * anim.current._value }}>
this line not work.
and your useEffect function just run one time only. because [] is empty.

useEffect(() => {
      
    }, []);